# What would it mean for a dipole moment not to be constant?

Tags: electromagnetism, dipole-moment

It is fairly easy to show that, for a neutral the electrostatic force on a neutral charge distribution with a dipole moment $\bf{p}$ is given by
$\bf{F}$$ = $$(\bf{p}$$\cdot \nabla)$$\bf{E}(r)$ if we can take the applied field $\bf{E}(r')$ as a two term Taylor expansion about a reference point $\bf{r}$ somewhere in the charge distribution (i.e. if the applied field varies slowly over the distribution).

In my textbook (Zangwill, Chapter 4.2.3), it is then noted that "When $\bf{p}$ is a constant vector..." we may use a standard vector identity (and the fact that we are in an electrostatic situation) to obtain $\bf{F}$$ = \nabla(\bf{p}\cdot\bf{E}(r))$.

I'm wondering when the dipole moment would NOT be constant (in terms of derivatives with respect to the reference point $\bf{r}$ which are taken to be zero in using the vector identity noted above)? Isn't the dipole vector always constant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many atoms/molecules do not have an inherent dipole moment.  Instead, their dipole moment is itself proportional to the external electric field experienced by the molecule:  $\mathbf{p} = \alpha \mathbf{E}$, where $\alpha$ is the atomic polarizability.  Such a molecule moving in a non-uniform electric field would not have a constant dipole moment.  The resulting force on the molecule would be $$\mathbf{F} = \alpha (\mathbf{E} \cdot \nabla) \mathbf{E} = \frac{1}{2} \alpha \nabla (E^2)$$ while we would have $$\nabla (\mathbf{p} \cdot \mathbf{E}) = \alpha \nabla (E^2)$$
which is obviously not the same.

Answer (score 3):

In the macroscopic Maxwell's equation the macroscopic displacement vector is defined by the dipole moment *density* $\mathbf P$ as $\mathbf D = \epsilon_0 \mathbf E + \mathbf P$ material. This means that locally we have an infinitesimal dipole moment $d \mathbf p= \mathbf P dV$ where both $\mathbf P$ and $d\mathbf p$ are functions of the location variable. The infinitesimal force acting on this infinitesimal dipole moment is $d\mathbf F = (d\mathbf p \cdot \nabla) \mathbf E$ reflecting the local variation of the dipole moment density and the force acting on it.
An obvious practical example of this would be an inhomogeneous dielectric whose permittivity is varying with location.

Comment: I follow this, and am willing to accept, I just want to add that I should have mentioned that I was looking for an example for a "true" charge distribution/electrostatic situation, not the "contrived" result arising from approximating a material's charge distribution via the polarization vector. If you have any such examples I would greatly appreciate it, otherwise I will go ahead and accept.

Comment: the example given above by @MichaelSeifert maybe what you are looking for but I would not call the macroscopic equations contrived. They represent as serious physics as thermodynamics or elasticity is, for example.

Comment: It is indeed. Still, thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: but be careful how you interpret $\alpha$ and $\mathbf E$ in @MichaelSeifert's example, for those are not microscopic quantities unless it is a molecule by itself, if for no other but that the microscopic field in a dielectric is time-varying and can never be really static.

Comment: Yes I agree. I think @MichaelSeifert was referring to a lone molecule moving though.